# Book on ASP.NET MVC for business apps, starting from scratch

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I’m looking for a book that explains how to use ASP.Net MVC, Razor and jQuery to build classic business applications (Forms over Data, lists of data, authentication) with modern techniques (client side validation, ajax forms posting, jQuery, CSS).

I want a book that assumes no knowledge of web development and IIS but that assumes advanced knowledge of .Net 4.0. A book with no reference to how it worked in WebForms would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve Sanderson has a [really good book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) on this.  It's more advanced, but if you have good knowledge of .net you should be OK. [Here's](http://www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/A101ZSV902JYNY/ref=cm_pdp_rev_title_1?ie=UTF8&sort_by=MostRecentReview#R72GUUN3I9QUA) Scott Guthrie's review of it as well.

Comment: Sanderson's latest edition of Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 should hit shelves pretty soon here. I read through the 2nd Edition (covered MVC 2) and it was an excellent source, if not the best. Undoubtedly Razor will be used exclusively in edition 3

Comment: I'm more than halfway through the 3rd edition and I can already say this is exactly the book I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don'nt think such single book has been published as of now. You will probaly have to go with a combination of books.  Even then I have not come across a book which covers razor.

In addition to the Sanderson book, I would suggest "Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns" by Scott Millett.